# Using jQuery to show/hide a div and then show/hide a div within that div

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a series of links nested within a div. When one of those links is clicked, I'd like to hide the div with the link that was clicked and show another div.  Then, if a link is clicked within that div, I'd like to change the div to yet another div.

The html looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="item"><a href="">Link to div A</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">Link to div B</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">Link to div C</a></div>
</div>

<div id="a" style="display:none;">Link to div <a href="">B</a> and <a href="">C</a></div>
<div id="b" style="display:none;">Link to div <a href="">A</a> and <a href="">C</a></div> 
<div id="c" style="display:none;">Link to div <a href="">A</a> and <a href="">B</a></div>
```

I'm getting a little tripped up with the jQuery on this one. Does anyone have any advice on how to get this working with jQuery? Showing/hiding a div seems straight forward, but doing that again within the divs is confusing me.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post what you have so far? It will help you avoid any griping from people about doing all the work for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're after, but I put together this jsFiddle for you to have a look at. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qsUVZ/1/).

I added a few changes so you can identify which anchors relate to which div, so my HTML looks as follows:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="item"><a href="#" name="a">Link to div A</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="#" name="b">Link to div B</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="#" name="c">Link to div C</a></div>
</div>

<div class="item" id="a" style="display:none;">
    Link to div <a href="#" name="b">B</a> and <a href="#" name="c">C</a>
</div>
<div class="item" id="b" style="display:none;">
    Link to div <a href="#" name="a">A</a> and <a href="#" name="c">C</a>
</div>
<div class="item" id="c" style="display:none;">
    Link to div <a href="#" name="a">A</a> and <a href="#" name="b">B</a>
</div>
```

Then, just a simple use of jQuery and it seems to work as you've described. Have a look at the jsFiddle I made and let me know if that's what you're after.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Hook up the first divs
    $(".item a").click(function() {

        // Get the target from the name of the anchor
        var targetDiv = $(this).attr("name");

        // Show the new div and hide the parent div
        $("#" + targetDiv).css("display", "");
        $(this).parents("div:last").css("display", "none");

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks - This is essentially what I am looking for.  The only issue I can't seem to resolve is that when I surround everything in another div, this no longer works.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qsUVZ/3/  Any clues why this is happening?  Thanks again.

Comment: It will hide everything because I am using "div:last" as the selector to find the first parent div. Here's a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/qsUVZ/4/. I added a class to each of the divs that should hide called "hide". So each time the link is click it hides all the divs with that class and then only shows the desired div.